# how to bench a css pseudo-elements

Tags: css, performance

Is there a way of measuring the performance (of displaying) for a web page with a lots of `:after` and `:before` in the CSS ?

I think there is a small impact on rendering time of each element, and there is no problem on a modern computer but on a slow mobile.

Comment: Create a test case, use a javascript loop to create 1000 div's, and then append content before and after them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Chromium Developer Tools now include a simple CSS selector timing profiler.

Open the Developer Tools (`F12` or `Ctrl + Shift + I`) and select "Profiles"; use the "Collect CSS Selector Profile". (You need to start the profiling and stop it after a while to see the results) You can switch the output from percentages to time measures in `ms` at the bottom of the DevTools-Window.

Comment: A nice feature ! start recording, refresh the page, wait, stop recording, enjoy !