# Is the use of CSS generated content (i.e. pseudo elements) more efficient (i.e. parsed/rendered faster) than adding more DOM elements?

Tags: css, performance, dom, pseudo-element, shadow-dom

In order to keep my mobile web app lean and efficient, I'm trying to limit the number of elements on the DOM at any given time. One way in which I intend to limit the use of DOM elements, is by using the pseudo `:before` and `:after` elements to generate content where possible.

For example, rather than representing a list-item with metadata like this:

```
<dd class="item">
    <div class="name">Name</div>
    <div class="desc">Description</div>
    <div class="location">Location</div>
    <div class="genre">Genre</div>
</dd>
```

I could represent it like this (& use the `content:` property to display the metadata):

```
<dd class="child" 
    data-name="Name" 
    data-desc="Description" 
    data-location="Location" 
    data-genre="Genre">
</dd>
```

So, one DOM element with data attributes as opposed to 5 separate elements and arguably cleaner markup.
Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/quc8b/2/

Will this technique actually improve performance? My thought is that with fewer DOM elements javascript should parse faster and I should be able to add/remove the list-item nodes faster. But will rendering (i.e. painting, layout, & reflows) occur faster? In other words, is CSS generated content rendered/parsed faster or more efficiently than traditional elements and text nodes?

How browsers internally handle CSS generated content in the render tree and document tree  is an unknown to me (shadow DOM maybe?). Are there any articles that discuss this?

Comment: Pseudo-elements do not exist in the DOM until a CSS rule inserts it before or after an element's. This means extra DOM manipulation although there is no additional logic required to match the selector itself.

Comment: There's a big difference between the two representations of the data, semantically speaking. The first indicates a definition with a name, description, location and genre. The second indicates a definition. And that's it. If nothing else, rendering the content via CSS is certainly not accessible.

Comment: @ricardohdz But is this method of DOM manipulation more efficient than manipulation via javascript?

Comment: If you are more concerned regarding performance, I would go and implement it via CSS, because Javascript will only traverse/manipulate the DOM after all the elements have been painted and the document is ready (at this point your CSS pseudo selector already have been applied).

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Agreed, but in my particular scenario how the data is represented in the markup is less of a concern to me than is efficiency. I'm wanting to understand the performance relationship between different types of DOM nodes and how they might affect layout/flow time and DOM traversal time via javascript. If less is accessible via JS and CSS, then perhaps this might improve performance?

Comment: @BigMacAttack Fair enough. The only way to answer performance questions like these, however, is to test it yourself, as your particular DOM may lend itself to one technique over another. See this article for an idea on how to benchmark CSS pseudo-elements: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13028891/how-to-bench-a-css-pseudo-elements

Answer (score 21):

I was also interested in figuring this out. So I did a simple litte test case.

I created two html pages for comparison:

**A. Pseudo-selectors:**

- HTML: 50.000 of these: `<p>paragraph</p>`
- CSS: `p:before { display: inline-block; width: 10px; height: 10px; margin-right: 5px; background-color: red; content: ""; }`

**B. Many DOM-elements:**

- HTML: 50.000 of these: `<p><span class="icon"></span> paragraph</p>`
- CSS: `.icon { display: inline-block; width: 10px; height: 10px; margin-right: 5px; background-color: red; }`

---

### Tests:

I used the Chrome Devtools Performance monitor running on a 2015 Macbook Pro.

#### Test1: "Start profiling and reload page"

Winner: A. Pseudo-selectors was ~400ms faster. It took 2033ms while option B took 2452ms.
I ran this test three times with similar results.

[image: screenshot]

#### Test2: Resizing the window

To measure re-layout I started a separate recording where I resized the browser window 3 times by changing from full-screen to half-screen (using shortcut keys in a window manager)

Winner: B. "Many DOM-elements" was ~330ms faster and took 1136ms to render while the other took 1463ms.

[image]

#### Test3: Reflows

I tried to cause reflows by measuring the page height using this piece of Javascript: `document.body.offsetHeight;`

Result: both were super fast at 4ms - so not no measurable difference.

---

PS: My 3 tests were just the ones that popped into my head - so not sure they prove anything really.

Answer (score -4):

> Please notice that **this answer was given years ago**. Many of the statements listed below are not valid anymore. Using pseudo-elements is still discouraged when serving content that should be accessible.

I don't know about the performance of pseudo-elements but I'm concerned that you put performance above everything else.

Pseudo-Elements have considerable drawbacks when compared to "real" DOM-Nodes:

- They can't be transitioned or animated
- You can't change their appearance dynamically with Javascript
- They are far less "important" to search engines
- They are cumbersome when it comes to debugging
- Their number is restricted to one `:before` and one `:after` element
- They aren't able to contain HTML-Tags, for example links or additional containers
- You hurt the concept of the separation of content and appearance
- Some HTML-Elements cannot have pseudo elements

For further reading, see the [Tag-Wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pseudo-element/info)

I'm sure there is more. On the other side is some sort of performance boost, which I believe, will be negligible.

Comment: In developing native-like embedded web applications (which is my use case), performance is critical. I am willing to tolerate certain CSS accessibility limitations if the overall technique can make the application more responsive.

Comment: Yeah, this doesn't answer the question.

Comment: They CAN be transitioned/animated

They CAN change appearance using JS (by adding classes/attributes, but it's possible).

They are NOT cumbersome in debugging (ever used Google Chrome Developer Tools?)

They can contain multiple information with single :before or :after, so 1 of each is enough.

There is NO separation of content and appearance issue with that.

Also, performance is crucial in many cases and using CSS to transform some elements into useful widgets is much easier than using JS and you don't need to clean it up

Comment: This was written more than two years ago. At this time, no dev-tools could display these elements.